# Every AVL tree may be red black tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, balanced-search-trees, check-my-answer

I proved by induction that every AVL tree may be colored such that it will be red black tree. The problem is that I can't see an error in my proof.  Look at my proof.

Induction for height.
Let's assume that it is truth for each AVL tree of height at most $h$.
Let's consider AVL tree $T$ of height $h+1$.  Now, let's consider two subtree of $T$ - $L$ and $R$. We know that $height(R)\le h$ and $height(L)\le h$.   Hence using induction hypothesis we conclude that $L$ and $R$ may be colored such that $L$ and $R$ will be red black tree.  Then we may paint root - of course black color.   Now $T$ is AVL and black tree.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? We don't like "look at my proof!" questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof produces a tree in which all nodes are colored black. It doesn't necessarily satisfy the "black height" rule:

> Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes contains the same number of black nodes.

Not every AVL tree satisfies this condition, for example the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AVLtreef.svg) doesn't.

Comment: Look, at wikipedia example once again. What about following coluouring http://i.imgur.com/7gWbjl1.png ?

Comment: @user40545 That's not the coloring that your proof produces.

Comment: Ah, ok I thought that You claied that there is no possiblity to color this graph.