# What is the maximal difference between the depths of 2 leaves in AVL tree?

Tags: balanced-search-trees, avl-trees

I'm wondering what's the answer of the following question:

What is the maximal difference between the depths of 2 leaves in an AVL tree?

Intuitively I think that it shouldn't exceed $log n$ but have no idea how to prove that. On the other hand, I saw multiple articles that claim the depth can become larger and larger without any formal proof (I always get a contradiction when trying to draw such trees)

I would really like if someone can explain me why it's correct\incorrect.

Comment: The maximum depth of an AVL tree is $O(\log n)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Properties. The difference can't exceed max depth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximal difference of height between two leaves in an AVL tree](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52077/maximal-difference-of-height-between-two-leaves-in-an-avl-tree)

Comment: @Evil Yes, thank you!